# How do I get the Entry Widget to pass into a function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm sure it is a simple mistake and I've localized it to a specific spot in the code:

```
class NewProduct(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)                

        tLabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Title: ", font=NORM_FONT).grid(row=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        qLabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Quantity: ", font=NORM_FONT).grid(row=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        pLabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Price: $", font=NORM_FONT).grid(row=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        te = ttk.Entry(self).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5) # Add validation in the future
        qe = ttk.Entry(self).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        pe = ttk.Entry(self).grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        saveButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Save", command=lambda: self.save(self.te.get(), self.qe.get(), self.pe.get()))
        #WHY IS THIS WRONG!!!!!???!?!?!?!?!?
        saveButton.grid(row=4, padx=5)
        cancelButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=lambda: popupmsg("Not functioning yet."))
        cancelButton.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5)

    def save(self, title, quantity, price):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("ComicEnv.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO cdata(unix, datestamp, title, quantity, price) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
                  (time.time(), date, title, quantity, price))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

I've tried a few different things including: 
`saveButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Save", command=lambda: self.save(te.get(), qe.get(), pe.get()))`

I'm trying to get the user input from the entry widget and store it in a sqlite3 database.

This is the Traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\aedwards\Desktop\deleteme.py", line 106, in <lambda>
    saveButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Save", command=lambda: self.save(self.te.get(), self.qe.get(), self.pe.get()))
AttributeError: 'NewProduct' object has no attribute 'te'
```

Any help you guys could give me would be greatly appreciated. Any more information, please just let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. When assigning attributes of a class, do `self.te = whatever`, not `te = whatever`. 2. Don't assign and pack on the same line. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/python-tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get

Comment: Could it be that simple? I'll try it now.

Comment: That did it. Thanks SO much.

I didn't even to think to look at the grid part. All that research and it was because I asked the wrong questions. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem: The `NewProduct` object has no attribute named `te`. You have created a local variable named `te`, but for it to be an attribute you must create `self.te`.

Also, you must call `grid` in a separate statement from where you create the widget, because `grid(...)` returns `None`, so `te` or `self.te` will also be none.  This not only solves that problem, but makes your code easier to understand, because you can put all of your calls to `grid` in the same block of code so you don't have your layout scattered all over the place.

For example:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.te = ttk.Entry(...)
    self.qe = ttk.Entry(...)
    self.pe = ttk.Entry(...)
    ...
    self.te = grid(...)
    self.qe = grid(...)
    self.pe = grid(...)
```

FWIW, I recommend *not* using lambda here. Create a proper function for your button to call. It's much easier to write and debug than a complicated lambda. There's rarely a need to use `lambda` in tkinter.

For example:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    saveButton = ttk.Button(..., command=self.on_save)
    ...

def on_save(self):
    title=self.te.get()
    quantity = self.qe.get()
    price = self.pe.get()
    self.save(title, quantity, price):
```

Comment: That does simplify the code a bit. I will change that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `def on_save ...` statement must be executed before the `ttk.Button` call.  This is not an issue if `def` is a method within a class and the call part of a set-up gui method of the same class.